# Como criar trigger para todas as tabelas de um banco, automaticamente?

Tags: sql, sql-server

#### Cenário exemplo

Tenho um banco de dados com **1.000 tabelas**.

**Uma** tabela chamada `log`.

---

#### Objetivo

Gostaria de criar uma **trigger "padrão"** em cada uma dessas tabelas, **de forma automática**.

Essa *trigger*, sempre que houver qualquer alteração (insert, update, delete) ela executar um `insert` na tabela `log`, com um `timestamp` e o `nome` da tabela em questão (extra seria o nome da(s) coluna(s)).

No mesmo contexto, gostaria de saber se há uma forma de **ver todas as triggers existentes em um banco de dados**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Penso que dessa forma conseguirá chegar ao que pretende:

```
CREATE TABLE [log]
(
        Id          UNIQUEIDENTIFIER    CONSTRAINT log_Id_DF        DEFAULT(NEWID())    NOT NULL
    ,   [Timestamp] DATETIME            CONSTRAINT log_Timestamp_DF DEFAULT(GETDATE())  NOT NULL
    ,   Tabela      NVARCHAR(255)       NOT NULL
    ,   Colunas     NVARCHAR(MAX)       NOT NULL
    ,   PRIMARY KEY (Id)
)

DECLARE @SQL AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

DECLARE cur_trigger CURSOR FOR
    SELECT      '
                    CREATE TRIGGER [' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[tr' + TABLE_NAME + '_auto]
                    ON [' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + TABLE_NAME + '] FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE AS
                    BEGIN
                        DECLARE @IdTabela   INT
                        DECLARE @Tabela     NVARCHAR(255)
                        DECLARE @Colunas    NVARCHAR(MAX)

                        SELECT  @Tabela = object_name(parent_id) 
                        FROM    sys.triggers 
                        WHERE   object_id = @@PROCID

                        SELECT  @IdTabela   = T.id
                        FROM    sysobjects P JOIN sysobjects T ON P.parent_obj = T.id 
                        WHERE   P.id = @@PROCID

                        SELECT  @Colunas = ISNULL(@Colunas + '', '', '''') + name 
                        FROM    syscolumns 
                        WHERE   id = @IdTabela   
                            AND CONVERT(VARBINARY, REVERSE(COLUMNS_UPDATED())) & POWER(CONVERT(BIGINT, 2), colorder - 1) > 0

                        INSERT INTO [log](Tabela, Colunas) VALUES(@Tabela, @Colunas)
                    END
                '
    FROM        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE       TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
            AND TABLE_NAME <> 'log'
    ORDER BY    TABLE_NAME

OPEN cur_trigger

FETCH NEXT FROM cur_trigger INTO @SQL

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    EXEC(@SQL)
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur_trigger INTO @SQL   
END

CLOSE cur_trigger
DEALLOCATE cur_trigger
```

Basicamente utiliza SQL dinâmico para construir o `trigger` e depois só tem de executar.

Em termos de sintaxe está correto, mas não foi testado no seu cenário.

Algumas ideias tiradas do **SOen**: [SQL Server Update Trigger, Get Only modified fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254787/sql-server-update-trigger-get-only-modified-fields)

---

Para consultar todos os `triggers` de uma base de dados, pode fazer o seguinte:

```
SELECT      *
FROM        sys.triggers  
WHERE       [type] = 'TR'
ORDER BY    [name]
```

Comment: João, vou testar assim que conseguir e te retorno! Só um caso que o Woss levantou, a tabela "log" não pode entrar na criação das triggers, se não viraria loop eterno... rs

Comment: E não entra @rbz, está antes do `CURSOR` :). De qualquer forma só o coloquei para ser um exemplo 100% funcional, mas claro, a tabela depois é criada como quiser.

Comment: Opa! Top! Preciso olhar com muita calma para digerir tudo isso! kkkk Pelo que estava vendo, ele irá listar até as colunas alteradas?

Comment: Sim, isso! Só precisa é testar na sua base de dados para confirmar que os _triggers_ são bem criados e são executados corretamente.

Comment: Está dando erro na criação da log, no tipo... mas eu vou testar no geral e te falo. Valeu professor!

Comment: Tem razão, não podem ser criada uma `DEFAULT CONSTRAINT` nas colunas do tipo `TIMESTAMP`. Resposta editada!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82787/discussion-between-rbz-and-joao-martins).

Comment: João, excluí tudo, executei novamente, e a tabela `log` está gerando tigger sim...

Comment: Mas é suposto a própria tabela, `log`, gerar registos em _log_? Porque se não for teremos que colocar uma cláusula para evitar isso.

Comment: Mas aí entra em loop infinito João. Se a trigger insere na `log` qualquer DML, ela iria sempre se "auto-disparar". Acho que um `AND TABLE_NAME <> 'log'` resolveria, certo?

Comment: Certo, isso! Vou editar a resposta para incluir esse cenário.

Comment: Funcionando perfeito! ✌️